# Django. При отправке письма для сброса пароля выскакивает ошибка NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index
from .views import other_page
from .views import BBLoginView
from .views import profile
from .views import BBLogoutView
from .views import ChangeUserInfoView
from .views import BBPasswordChangeView
from .views import RegisterUserView, RegisterDoneView
from .views import user_activate
from .views import DeleteUserView
from .views import PasswordChangeView
from .views import PasswordChangeDoneView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetCompleteView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetDoneView


app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/activate/<str:sign>/', user_activate, name='register_activate'),
    path('accounts/logout/', BBLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('account/profile/delete/', DeleteUserView.as_view(), name='profile_delete'),
    path('accounts/profile/change', ChangeUserInfoView.as_view(), name='profile_change'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('<str:page>/', other_page, name='other'),
    path('accounts/register/done/', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name='register_done'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/login/', BBLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('accounts/password/change/', BBPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('accounts/password/resetting/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_resetting'),
    path('accounts/password/resetting/done/', PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_resetting_done'),
    path('accounts/password/reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='main/password_reset.html',
        subject_template_name='email/reset_subject.txt',
        email_template_name='main/reset_email.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('accounts/password/reset/done', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='main/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='main/password_confirm.html'
    ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('accounts/password/reset/done/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_done_complete'),
]
```

html

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block title %}Отправка письма {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Отправка письма</h2>
    {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
    {% buttons submit='Отправить' %}{% endbuttons %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: а текст ошибки можно в текстовом формате?

Comment: @МихаилРебров   ок

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил